# LIMIT X but extend range for ending fields that match.

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm working on a data entry system that requires totalling the sum of all of a users transactions before entry. The database I'm pulling from does not have a field for the totalling, and we're expected to do it within the program. I'm trying to pull out the transactions in chunks of 100 for entry, but I need to make sure I'm not messing up the totals if the transaction at line 100 and 101 have the same customer. Is there any way to do a variable limit where the range is extended if the last name fields of the last rows in the limit are the same?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, Postgres doesn't support the `WITH TIES` option on `FETCH`.  One method to do what you want uses a subquery.

I'm not sure exactly what you query looks like, but this gives the idea:

```
select t.*
from transactions t
where t.customer_id in (select t2.customer_id
                        from transactions t2
                        order by ?
                        fetch first 100 rows only
                       )
order by ?;
```

The `?` is for the column that specifies the ordering.